# Finding particular value of joint CDF of discrete random vector

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I can only find a brute-force solution to the following problem:

> A fair coin is flipped until it comes up "heads" for the first time.
>   Every time the coin is flipped, a fair six-sided die is thrown.
>   Let $N$ be the number of coin-flips and $S$ be the sum of all the die-throw results. 
>   What is the probability of the event $N\leq 4 \; \cap S\leq 7$? 
>   (or equivalently, what is the value of $F_{N,S}(4,7)$ ?)

Is there a neat way (either combinatoric or probability-theoretic) to find the solution?

I know that $N\sim Geom(1/2)$, so that all we need to find is the conditional probabilities of $S\leq 7$ on the different values of $N$, but this still leaves a lot of dirty counting to be done.

Trying to present $S$ as a linear combination of simpler random variables also didn't seem to provide any shortcuts.. (But maybe I'm missing a clever way to do it)

Thanks

Comment: I would not call the conditional probabilities "a lot of dirty counting".  You are perhaps looking at an $O(ab)$ size calculation to find all the values of $F_{N,S}(x,y)$ with $1\le x\le a, 1 \le y \le b$

Comment: You can just use a convolution of the generating function of N and S, since S is a random sum: $S=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $X_i$ is discrete uniform on $[1,6]$ and $N$~$Geom(\frac 12)$.  Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Functions_of_independent_random_variables

Comment: Sure! The Probability Generating Function, for some random variable S, has the form: $E(z^S)=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}P(S=s)z^s$. Essentially we would like to match coefficients of the generating function (check out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343693/deriving-probability-density-function-from-probability-generating-function-for-r). To get the generating function, we use the idea of a convolution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Functions_of_independent_random_variables. If you get stuck we can try to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got confused there between the probability generating function and the moment generating function. Will give this a try! thanks again.